# Is it consistent to add a generalization axiom on top of Ext.+Subworld Separation+Reduciblity?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Let's work with Harvey Friedman's theory ${\sf K}(W)$ as in his seminar notes "[Axiomatization of Set Theory by Extensionality, Separation, and Reducibility](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/TalkAxiomSetThy-ts05xn.pdf)", formulated in the language of set theory with a primitive constant symbol $W$ added, i.e. in ${\sf FOL}(\in,W)$

**Axioms:**

**Extensionality:** $$\forall Z \, (Z \in X \iff Z \in Y) \implies \\\forall Z \, (X \in Z \iff Y \in Z)$$

**Subworld Separation:** $$\forall A \in W \, \exists X \in W \, \forall Y \, (Y \in X \iff Y \in A \land \phi)$$; where formula $\phi$ doesn't use the symbol "$X$".

**Reducibility:** if $\phi$ is a formula in ${\sf FOL} (\in)$, with all parameters among "$X,\vec{P}$ " then: $$\forall \vec{P} \in W [ (\exists X: \phi) \implies \exists X \in W: \phi]$$

/

Which is equiconsistent with ZFC.

Is it consistent to add the following principle:

**Generalization:** if $\phi$ is a formula in ${\sf FOL} (\in)$, with all parameters among symbols "$X,\vec{P}$ "; then: $$ \forall \vec{P} \in W [(\forall \operatorname {infinite} X \in W: \phi) \implies \phi(W)]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalization holds in K(W). Suppose it did not, that ¬(W) holds and ∀infinite∈:.

Then ∃X((infiniteX)∧¬), since this is true when X is W. By Reducibility

∃X∈W((infiniteX)∧¬). But this contradicts the fact that ∀infinite∈:.